# C# managed code errors not appearing in Winqual

Tags: c#, c++, windows-error-reporting

I’m hoping someone can help me track down why our WER is not working as I expect it to.

I have a large .Net 2.0 application that usually runs on a Windows Embedded Standard 2009.  This application is made up of a Core C# application that uses several C# dlls some of which in turn use other c# dlls and some C++ dlls.

I have uploaded several mapping files (for different versions) to the Winqual website, and am receiving events corresponding to these mappings.  However none of the events are based on the Managed C# code, it all seems to be based on the unmanaged C++ code.  I have triggered some crashes in the Managed c# code and they have been sent to Winqual, but they don’t seem to be showing up on the Winqual website.

Does anyone know why this might occur?

Comment: Sure, neither WER nor Winqual know anything about managed code.  They only get the unmanaged view of the process.  All they know about a managed exception is the exception code, 0xe0434f4d.

Comment: But if an exception happens in managed code it still asks if I want to send an error report to Winqual.  Surely this should get recorded in Winqual, and then I can download the minidump and review it using SOS.  Or at least this is my expectation.